# .caf file in app not playing in iPod

Tags: avaudioplayer

In my app, i have some .caf audio file (Format: IMA 4:1, Stereo, 44.100 kHz). The problem what i m facing is that these audio file plays on button action (one button for each ringtone).They are playing fine on iphone(ios version 3 to 5 ) but im not able to listen it on ipod. I have done all the sound setting changes as solution described on other site but nothing happens.
Also ipod not stuck in headphone mode(this problem happens sometime when we plug out headphone while any audio file is playing).So please give any solution as soon as possible.

Comment: i suggest that u play mp3 format not issue give by that format@himanshu.

Comment: but these were playing previously.And it suddenly stop playing even i do not make any changes in the code.My code is:NSString *any = [ringtonesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:any ofType:@"caf"];
 playRingtone = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:nil];
 [playRingtone play];

Answer (score 0):

first You import framework then use below code:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
```

call whenever you want by this method:

```
[self BackgroundSound:@"sounf file name"];//must have in resource(.wav,.mp3,.caf)
```

write this function by above method for call that :

```
- (void)BackgroundSound:(NSString *) name 
{
    NSString *spath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
  AVAudioPlayer*  BackgroundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:spath] error:nil];
    BackgroundPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; // set to -1 to loop repeated
    BackgroundPlayer.volume = 0.5; // value is from 0 to 1.0 (float)
    [BackgroundPlayer play]; // play
}
```

work in iPad/iPhone both in my application. i hope ,it's help you also.

Comment: the only difference between ur and mine code as "audioplayer.volume = 0.5",which can be the reason but even after putting this in my code the   audio file does not sound.

Comment: 1st you have to try another file of sound like ".mp3" format.what done say to me then.

Comment: what is reason of using mp3? If from starting i was using .caf file and it was playing fine on ipod and iphone but suddenly it stop playing on ipod but playing finally on iphone....that is totally weird and thats why why i asked this qsn if any one also faced this problem and got a solution..